# My Iphone App crashes (Bad access) when turned on it's side (landscape mode)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation, accelerometer, landscape

For some reason, every time I run my Iphone App, the App works fine as long as it is upright. The second the simulator turns to the left or right (like if I manually turn it, or if it's trying to play a video), the code crashes, with either a "Bad Access" or an exception.

The crazy thing is that this stuff was JUST working, and I didn't change ANYTHING that looks like it would affect landscape mode only. Could something complicated in the background have changed to make this stop working? Is this just a symptom of some sort of memory error?

-Jenny

Comment: Please post the crash log, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could be releasing something which should shouldn't release yet, or similar.

I'd put some `NSLog` statements in key places, start with `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and in any custom drawing functions you may have.

Comment: I'm...I'm so confused. It's working now, after h ours and hours of debugging. All I did was add a break point to some of those view controllers (like where I found Autorotate, etc.)...and it worked. I thought maybe it was because I was stepping through it, but now everything works, even on iphones that I KNOW I haven't changed code on. I'm so confused....

Comment: Hmmm...  I'd really go back to figure out the cause though.  Remove the break points, clean the project, rebuild it and see what happens.

Comment: I did, and it still worked. Days later I figured out that the network I was on was speeding up (end of work day), which changed things. What turned out to be the problem is that I was releasing something that was autoreleasing. The crash only happened if I tried to release it after it had already released (because my network was running slow)